# Integrating Spring Security authentication with an Oauth2 server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have the following web security configuration class for an AngularJS application hosted on Spring Boot (1.3.0):

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/bower_components/**", "/templates/login/**",
                        "/fonts/**", "/user")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    }

     @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("myuser").password("password").roles("USER");
        }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

How can I simply substitute the configureGlobal method to authenticate with an Oauth2 server that only has grant types of "refresh_token" and "password"?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question (or if I do it's a rather unusual application of OAuth2). You want to provide an `AuthenticationManager` that makes a remote call to an OAuth2 auth server using password grant?

Comment: @DaveSyer That's right, let's assume we have an Oauth2 server that is external to this application. Is it possible to link Spring Security to that server via an AuthenticationManager? My initial approach would've been to create a custom AuthenticationProvider and there call the Oauth2 services using RestTemplate but I don't know if that would be problematic. Thank you for replying to my questions, right now I am evaluating the features and flexibility of Spring Security's Oauth project.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with that, but it's a bit odd. Why don't you just POST to a login form?